# How to stop using homophones in written English

Tags: homophones

I am not natively an English speaker, though it is a taught language from childhood and I have been using the language long enough. I have a problem though with using homophones instead of the actual words intended when writing. I have since noted that I do this usually when I am typing/writing and thinking something else at that moment (generally multitasking).

**Examples**
know-no
knew-new

Since I am only ever going to be exposed to more of adulthood, which dictates that I do have many of this multitasking, does anyone suffer from this, and how can I deal with this.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with you not being a native English speaker. I make such typos all the time when I'm distracted and the words don't always need to sound the same. For example, requestion sometimes happens when I mean to type requesting. The easiest solution is to either focus on what you're doing, or to wait to send what you've written until you've proof-read it when you can focus.

Comment: What @ColleenV said. *Real* language is *spoken* - the ability to both know and *apply* recognized (but often, bordering on arbitrary) rules of orthography / spelling is only peripherally related to language skills. But there's definitely a difference between not being able to spell the word you *do* mean, and absent-mindedly typing a homonym. Because the latter won't be picked up by a simple spellchecker, but will often be far more disruptive to many *readers*, it ends up looking worse than is justified. I read almost nothing about a person's language skills from homophonous "typos".

Comment: (But I would of thought I'd be in good company if I [facepalmed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facepalm) at *this* sentence! :) Though it's a moot point whether that **of** instead of **have = 've** is a "homophone" error.

Comment: I really think all of us do this from time to time, especially when we're in a hurry or tired.

Answer (score 2):

Different brains work in different ways, but perhaps explaining how I avoid it will work for you.

I would never make the know/no mistake because I know (hehe) the roots of the word. The '**kn**' in '**kn**ow' is a sound that is absolutely everywhere in Indo-European languages. My pro**gn**osis is that you are a**gn**ostic of, or perhaps even i**gno**rant of, and most certainly not co**gn**isant to the fact that if you look at German (**ken**nen), Greek (**γν**ῶσις), Russian (**зн**ати - **zn**ati), Latin (co**gno**sco), or Sunscrit (**jñ**a), you can reco**gn**ize this sound everywhere through its various co**gn**ates.

So that was silly, but the point is, you won't make those mistakes if you understand where the words come from. Good luck and have fun!

Comment: The German cognate is _kennen_. The "g" in _gewußt_ is a perfective prefix.

Comment: @ColinFine yeah I used the perfective because it more clearly illustrates my point, but I'm not a German speaker so I'll take your advice.

Comment: @ColinFine oh now I see what you're saying. You are correct. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

These two links might help you:

- http://www.suburgian.com/homophone-checker-microsoft-word/
- http://www.techrepublic.com/article/macro-trick-how-to-highlight-multiple-search-strings-in-a-word-document/

The first uses Microsoft Word's index feature, and the second uses a macro, both to indicate instances of words from a list that you specify. You could find a list of common homophones and customize it to your personal mistakes.

I don't have any experience using either of these features, so you may need to do some more research (probably on the Stack Overflow community). However, these are some places to start that could provide you with a tool to help you check for homophones quickly.

Comment: Thank you. A tool to help you check words you might be mistaking for others is a good start!